# create tcolorbox- multirows, multicolumns

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to create a `tcolorbox`:

```
Name

A1|B1|C1

M2|N2|K2

X3|Y3|Z3
```

My minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[colback=red!15!white,colframe=red!65!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,fontlower=\itshape] %

%
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,title=Name]
A1
\tcblower
B1

%\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Minion_Tips.png}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I add more columns and more rows?

Thanks

Comment: Go to [the `tcolorbox` package manual](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) and search for the keyword "table" or "tabular", you will find many results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document} %

%
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Name,
                  width=5cm,
                  colback=red!15!white,
                  colframe=red!65!black,
                  fonttitle=\bfseries,
                  tabularx={C|C|C},
                                   ]
             %
        A1 & B1 & C1\\
        M2 & N2 & K2 \\
        X3 & Y3 & Z3
        %
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good. I left this question because it was impossible for me to solve it with the OP code. In fact the hatching creates only two lines or only two columns as per the manual.